# Jackson convertValue with RepresentationModel objects

Tags: json, spring, data-binding, jackson, spring-hateoas

I have a class that extends `RepresentationModel` from Spring Hateoas. I have no problem converting an object of this class to `JsonNode` but exceptions are thrown when converting back from `JsonNode` to this class using Jackson `convertValue`.

And the reason for that is there is a `links` field added to the object by `RepresentationModel` and the field is not defined in the class--it's inherited from `RepresentationModel`. So upon calling the method `convertValue(jsonNode, ObjExtendsRepresentationModel.class)`, I'm getting `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('self')`

So my question is it possible to make Jackson go quiet and complete the conversion when `convertValue` method comes across a json property that is not defined in the object class? So far, I've tried setting `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to false but this did not help at all.

**Update:**

```
public class AResource extends RepresentationModel<AResource> {
    private final String aField;
    private final String bField;
    public AResource(String aField, String bField) {
        this.aField = aField;
        this.bField = bField;
    }
}

...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));       
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
JsonNode existing = mapper.convertValue(aResource, JsonNode.class);

...

AResource reverted = mapper.convertValue(existing, AResource.class);
```